# My LiveData variable is not working correctly

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata

I have a livedata int value Its value is initially 3.
In fragment Quiz its value decreases and becomes 0. But in fragment End its value still remains 3, why?

ViewModel

```
class QuizViewModel : ViewModel() {
    
    private val lives = MutableLiveData<Int>()
    var live = 3

    init {
        lives.value = live
    }

    fun onWrongAnswer() {
        live--
    }

    fun onPlayAgain() {
        live = 3
    }
}
```

QuizFragment

For each wrong answer, the live decreases by 1 and if it is 0 or the questions are finished, the EndFragment is reached.

EndFragment

```
  private fun checkResult() {
        if (viewModel.live == 0) {
            binding.imageViewResult.setImageResource(R.drawable.sad)
            binding.textViewResult.setText(R.string.you_lose_want_to_try_again)
        } else {
            binding.imageViewResult.setImageResource(R.drawable.won)
            binding.textViewResult.setText(R.string.you_win_congratulations)
        }
    }
```

This part does not work correctly because it remains as Live 3. But its value decreased and became 0. Why is it 3 again?

Comment: I suggest you use a more expressive title to avoid downvotes.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for the title?

Answer (score 0):

You check the `Int` `live` instead of the `MutableLiveData<Int>` `lives`.

Get rid of `live` and create a non-mutable public livedata member variable. Update the mutable live data in your viewmodel:

```
private val _lives = MutableLiveData<Int>(3)
val lives: LiveData<Int> = _lives
fun onWrongAnswer() {
    _lives.value = lives.value?.minus(1)
}

fun onPlayAgain() {
    _lives.value = 3
}
```

Observe the value of the `lives: LiveData` in your fragment like this:

```
viewModel.lives.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {live ->
    if (live == 0) {
        binding.imageViewResult.setImageResource(R.drawable.sad)
        binding.textViewResult.setText(R.string.you_lose_want_to_try_again)
    } else {
        binding.imageViewResult.setImageResource(R.drawable.won)
        binding.textViewResult.setText(R.string.you_win_congratulations)
    }
})
```

Note: `viewLifecycleOwner` is a property from `androidx.fragment.app`.

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for this descriptive answer. I did as you said, but in this case I got some errors in QuizFragment:                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 Operator '==' cannot be applied to 'LiveData<Int>' and 'Int'

Comment: `private fun checkQuestionIndexAndLives() {
        if (questionIndex == maxIndex || viewModel.lives == 0) {
            goToEndPage()
        } else {
            observeLiveData()
        }
 }`

Comment: You need to access the value inside the live data. Use `viewModel.lives.value == 0`

Comment: Thank you very much, I am a beginner in this subject, your descriptive answer will help me a lot.

Comment: @alicealice Remember to mark this post as answered ;)